# Bootstrap-vue no muestra el espacio inline por defecto en los botones

Tags: css, bootstrap, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Tengo unos botones en bootstrap-vue y no se muestra el espacio inline que hay por defecto entre los botones:

[image: Image from Gyazo]

resultado:

[image: Image from Gyazo]

No encuentro el problema, he revisado varios post al respecto, pero todos tratan de remover ese espacio en vez de quererlo.

EDIT: Un usuario, asumiendo que no sé formular preguntas me ofrece la posibilidad de pegar todo el codigo del componente. A lo mejor así se ve un poco mas claro que estoy usando exclusivamente clases de bootstrap-vue por defecto y nada de CSS personalizado. Simplemente no funciona como debe.

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col text-left">

                <h2>Listado de Libros</h2>

                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <b-table striped hover :items="books" :fields="fields">

                        <template v-slot:cell(action)="data">

                                <b-button size="sm" variant="primary">Editar</b-button>
                                <b-button size="sm" variant="danger">Eliminar</b-button>

                        </template>

                    </b-table>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<style>
</style>
```

Comment: Hola, en mi opinión no veo mal tu pregunta, he visitado recurrentemente el sitio y a veces no entiendo por qué contestan cosas si están pésimamente redactadas y no tienen pies ni cabeza. También he notado que algunos suelen comentar que se tiene que mejorar (solo por no tener código escrito ¿?), pero no se dan a la tarea de editar a la pregunta, copian y pegan un comentario y ya, imagino que obtienen ventaja al llenarse de positivos, solo por hacer eso.

En fin, te sugiero usar spacing en caso de que no lo hayas utilizado aún https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/vue/utilities/spacing/  Suerte.

Comment: Hola gracias por tu comentario. Anteriormente he tenido este error de spacing por defecto en otro proyecto y lo solucionaba agregando en mi caso `mr-2`. Pero en este caso tampoco funciona. Ni toma el espacio por defecto ni funcionan las clases predefinidas de spacing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como se indica en la [documentación de Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/): m es para margen. Y luego puedes poner un número para indicar el tamaño del márgen. Por ejemplo, me funcionó colocando `m-1`.